# Correct preamble with T1 font encoding

Tags: math-mode, fonts, packages, input-encodings, font-encodings

I am wondering if I have set up a correct preamble. In particular I must use T1 encoding, because I am writing in Portuguese.

```
\documentclass[english,portuguese]{article}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

[...]

\end{document}
```

- I would like to know if I really need to load the `babel` package, since I put the languages in `\documentcass[.]`.
- My main question is about the influence of `T1` encoding. Searching I found to correct the quality of the written text it is necessary to use package `lmodern` or `cm-super`. In my case, I chose to use `lmodern`. But in the places where I found the suggestion to use these pacores, answers have been given for some time, so I don't know if there is a better option today. I would also like to know if `T1` also influences the font of the mathematical environment, that is, if the quality decreases. And so if there is any package to help resolve this.
- Is the second block of packages correct? Do they make sense given that the `T1` package was loaded?
- I know that the order that some packages are loaded can influence their effectiveness, so is the order that I loaded my packages right?

The main reason why I use `T1` is that the search works correctly in `pdf` and that it is possible to copy and paste, so if I print my material, I can then compile the same `.tex` file, without `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage{lmodern}` options to get a file for did I print with quality, without having to change anything else in the `.tex` file?

**Additional information:** I'm using `pdflatex` on TeXstudio on *Windows*.

Comment: It looks okay. You don’t need `amsfonts` if you loaded `amssymb`. If copying and searching in Unicode is important, you might want to add `\usepackage{mmap}` to include Unicode mappings in your PDF file. I also normally `\usepackage{microtype}` for font protrusion and expansion.

Comment: Portuguese is similar enough to English that you only need `babel` for localization and hyphenation patterns.

Comment: My advice, which not everyone agrees with, is to use `fontspec` and modern fonts when you can, and legacy 8-bit fonts when you have to. Some publishers, such as the arXiv, still force you to in 2020.